# Approximations of algebraic numbers and Schmidt subspace theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory

In Schmidt paper https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-125/issue-none/Simultaneous-approximation-to-algebraic-numbers-by-rationals/10.1007/BF02392334.full

Schmidt proves the corollary: let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be real $\mathbb Q$-linearly independant algebraic numbers and $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists only fintely many rationals $(p_1/q,\cdots,p_n/q)$ such that $|a_i-\frac{p_i}q|\le\frac1{q^{1+1/n+\varepsilon}}$.

Can one easily prove this corollary by using Schmidt subspace theorem?

Comment: This is an immediate corollary of the subspace theorem. The better place to ask that question is math.stackexchange.com

Comment: If it is immediate, you could write a few lines to explain  it.

Comment: Apply subspace theorem to linear forms $L_0(p_1,\dots,p_n,q)=q$, $L_i(p_1,\dots,p_n,q)=q\alpha_i-p_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Then check that any proper subspace can contains only finitely many solutions. If you need more details, ask on math.stackexchange